# Promises => Async/Await....Does this have any benefits?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I'm working through my express server controllers and refactoring from `promises` to `async/await`. For some of the functions, I'm unsure if I'm doing it just for the sake of it. If it's not any more readable, should I still do it?

Here's an example:

```
async sharedTroop(req, res, next) {
    const firebaseUID = req.params.uid;

    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ firebaseUID }).select('troopPointTotal');

      user.troopPointTotal += 1000;

      try {
        user.save();
        try {
          res.send(user);
        } catch (e) {
          next(e);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        next(e);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      next(e);
    }
  }
```

Does the above (using `async/await`) have any benefits over this?:

```
sharedTroop(req, res, next) {
    const firebaseUID = req.params.uid;

    User.findOne({ firebaseUID })
      .select('troopPointTotal')
      .then(user => {
        user.troopPointTotal += 1000;
        user.save().then(() => res.send(user));
      })
      .catch(next);
  },
```

And if the refactoring hasn't improved readability, should I not bother?

Thanks!

Comment: @downvoters: please comment

Comment: some people can't handle non-imperative style of coding - async/await allows a more imperative style - but this is opinion

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to nest the `try` statements:

```
async sharedTroop(req, res, next) {
  const firebaseUID = req.params.uid;
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ firebaseUID }).select('troopPointTotal');
    user.troopPointTotal += 1000;
    user.save();
    res.send(user);
  } catch(e) {
    next(e);
  }
}
```

This might look a lot better than the nested callbacks of your `then` solution indeed. It also simplifies fixing your mistake: You will want to `await` the result of `user.save()` before sending the response - and then the `catch` will implicitly handle errors from the save process. In contrast, your `then` version has a similar mistake: by not `return`ing the result of `user.save().then(() => res.send(user))` from the callback, errors will not be handled by the `.catch()` in the end.

> If the refactoring hasn't improved readability, should I not bother?

Sure, readability is subjective, and if you think there's no advantage then you should not bother to reactor.

Comment: Thank you! I notice in your code snippet above that you did not `await` the result of `user.save()`  or `res.send(user)`. Should this be done?

Comment: @MattCleary I did not because the code in the question didn't either. But yes, I'm pretty certain that you *should* `await user.save()`. `send` doesn't return a promise afaik so there's nothing to wait for.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer NO, `async/await` is only a syntactic sugar for the code you wrote with `then / catch`.

The only benefit is order at your eyes. There is no need for callback, you mimic "synchronous" code style.